# Convert From Byte[] to File

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file-conversion

I use the following Function to convert a file to Byte()

```vb
Public Function FileToByteArray(ByVal _FileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim _Buffer() As Byte = Nothing

    Try
        ' Open file for reading
        Dim _FileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

        ' attach filestream to binary reader
        Dim _BinaryReader As New System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream)

        ' get total byte length of the file
        Dim _TotalBytes As Long = New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length

        ' read entire file into buffer
        _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(CInt(Fix(_TotalBytes)))

        ' close file reader
        _FileStream.Close()
        _FileStream.Dispose()
        _BinaryReader.Close()
    Catch _Exception As Exception
        ' Error
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString())
    End Try

    Return _Buffer
End Function
```

I save the file (`"C:\sample.xlsx"`) using this function to database(I use Microsoft SQL Server) as `SqlDbType.Image`

Below is the code that I use to get the value from db and try to convert it as a file again.

```vb
Dim FileInBinary() As Byte
Dim CurrentRS As Recordset

'Select
SQLString = "SELECT FileInBinary from table where ID=1"

'Get value to a recordSet
CurrentRS = ServerRunSQL_Return(SQLString)

'SaveValue to Dim
FileInBinary = CurrentRS.Fields(0).Value

'Try to convert
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("C:\sample_new.xlsx", FileInBinary, True)
```

I also tried:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\sample_new.xlsx", FileInBinary)
```

How can I select this value and convert it again as file (`"C:\sample_new.xlsx"`)?

Comment: You're saying you took the result of `FileToByteArray("C:\sample.xlsx")` and stored it in a database and you want to know how to read it back from the database and write it to a file? Can you post your code for the database retrieval operation since the code in the question doesn't appear to be...in question? By the way, when reading the file you could also get the length from `_FileStream.Length` instead of creating a `FileInfo`, but, really, you could just replace the whole function with a call to [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes).

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Where and how is the above code failing?  Is it throwing an `Exception`, or is `FileInBinary` simply `Nothing`/empty?  Depending on the answers to those questions it might be helpful to include the code for `ServerRunSQL_Return()` and the value of `SQLString` as well.

Comment: Start by getting rid of that `FileToByteArray` method.  There's already a method that gets a `Byte` array from a file and that's `File.ReadAllBytes`.  If you're doing anything else then you're probably corrupting the data.  If you read the data using `File.ReadAllBytes` then you will find that writing the data using `File.WriteAllBytes` will work.  If that doesn't work then you're corrupting the data somewhere else, so you'd need to show all the code that gets the result of `ReadAllBytes` into the database and out again.

Comment: OH MY GOD! Why on Earth are you using a `Recordset`?  We're not in VB6 any more Toto.  You should get acquainted with ADO.NET.  Use a `SqlCommand` and its `ExecuteNonQuery` method to save a single record to a SQL Server database or a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable` to save multiple records. To get a single value, call `ExecuteScalar` on a `SqlCommand`.  See examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases).

Comment: I tried SqlCommand and i get this error 
**The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.**
I use a stored procedure which is:   `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spShow_AttInBinary] ( 
   @FileInBinary image Output 
         )
AS 
set @FileInBinary=(select FileImage from table WHERE ID=1)`

Comment: I just post the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please stop using `image`. That datatype has been deprecated since **2005**. You also seem to have expended a lot of effort just to replicate `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Function FileToByteArray with `File.ReadAllBytes("C:\sample.xlsx")`

Below is the code  to get the value from db and convert it as a file again.

```
Dim FileInbinary As Byte()
SqlConn.Open()
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT FileInBinary from table where ID=1", SqlConn) 
FileInbinary = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
SqlConn.Close()
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\sample_new.xlsx", FileInbinary)
```